# Log messages from Web API to console in .NET 4 and IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-6

Coming from Java servlet containers, I really find it annoying that the IIS server (I am stuck with **IIS6 on Windows Server 2003**) does not have a console output that can be used to **log messages** into.

Is there a way to do this? I'd like to debug a particularly specific hardware/software deploy configuration that doesn't make my RESTful service, written with WebAPIs in .NET 4, work properly.

I'm thinking if there is some way to write to an output buffer and then consume it by attaching to that particular stream from a `cmd` console window.

Thank you.

Comment: log4net supports log into console, you could try this

Comment: The question still is: "how do I connect to the console that outputs the messages?"

Comment: you want to connect console in order to do what?

Comment: In order to read log lines as they are written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing events in the Windows Event log. A crappy solution for a crappy way of doing stuff, if you ask me.